# SmartWatch extension starting

Tags: android, sony-smartwatch

From my extension, I can start the Call Handling extension with this code:

```
 Intent i1 = new Intent("com.sonyericsson.extras.aef.control.START_REQUEST");
  i1.putExtra("aea_package_name", "com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension.call");
  i1.setPackage("com.sonyericsson.extras.smartwatch");
  mContext.sendBroadcast(i1, "com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.HOSTAPP_PERMISSION");
```

But I cannot start my own extension, nor any other third-party extensions in the same way:

```
Intent i2 = new Intent("com.sonyericsson.extras.aef.control.START_REQUEST");
  i2.putExtra("aea_package_name", "eir.log");
  i2.setPackage("com.sonyericsson.extras.smartwatch");
  mContext.sendBroadcast(i2, "com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.HOSTAPP_PERMISSION");
```

The i2 intent works properly, when it's called from a different app, but not from an extension.

I'm puzzled. Is the Call Handling extension receiving some special treatment from the Host app, or what is the problem?

Comment: Can you add the manifest start tag of your Android manifest?

Comment: @mdiener I'm not sure I understand you correctly, I don't know what difference does it make... here it is, anyway: `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      package="my.package" android:versionName="3.1" android:versionCode="12"> `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two ways to solve this issue:

1) Trigger stopping of the current extension before invoking the other. This happens to work with the latest SmartWatch 2, but as far as I remember, it didn't work on the original SmartWatch.

What is safer to do, in case you're starting your own extensions:

2) Define a custom intent which the extension you want to start would receive (that's, of course, done in the Manifest file); then broadcast that intent from your other extension. I chose this way, also because it enables me to pass data to the extension.

Vote up, if you find this solution useful :-)